# Here is a Sql-Server query, How do it in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, auto-increment

Here is a SQL-Server query, How do it in PostgreSQL?

```
DECLARE @p_key as int= NEXT VALUE FOR  ProductSequence;
INSERT INTO Product(ID,Name,Price) VALUES(@p_key,@Name,@Price);
INSERT INTO ProductInfo(ID,Guid,DateCreation, DateLastChange, AgentCreationID,AgentLastChangeID) VALUES(@p_key, @Guid, @DateCreation, @DateLastChange, @AgentCreationID, @AgentLastChangeID);
SELECT  @p_key;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `product.id` is defined as `identity` you can do that with a writeable CTE:

```
with new_product as (
  insert into product (name, price)
  values (...)
  returning id
)
insert into product_info (id, guid, date_creation, date_last_change, anget_creation_id, agent_last_change_id )
select id, 'guid', ...
from new_product;
```

Otherwise just use `nextval()` and `lastval()`

```
insert into product 
  (id, name, price)
values 
  (nextvalue('product_id_seq'), ...);

insert into product_info 
  (id, guid, date_creation, date_last_change, anget_creation_id, agent_last_change_id )
values 
  (lastval(), ....);
```

Comment: The first is fine,  Just for second solution, for the lastval(..), it could pick another value in concurrent environment, is it ?

Comment: No, if all statements are run in the same session/connection that can't happen